# Routing issue with angularjs while version update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-routing

**Scenario** : I have update my current angularjs version from **AngularJS v1.5.5**  to **AngularJS v1.5.7**. Application is working fine but there is issue with URL routing it is behaving different. Let's see acceptance criteria below.

**Try 1**

Original URL as below and this is the expected result also.

https://u-unalytix.milestoneinternet.com/Unalytix.Web.UAT/dashboard/marketing-channels

Just after update version I was getting error with commented lines which below.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
// $urlrouterprovider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
       // var path = $location.path();
       // if (path != '/' && path.slice(-1) === '/') {
          // $location.replace().path(path.slice(0, -1));
       // }
// });
```

**Result** :

https://u-unalytix.milestoneinternet.com/U/dashboard/marketing-channels

You can see here due to some reason we are not getting the expected result.Then I try with another code of piece in **module.config**. After googling I got some answer to resolve this issue and I tried as follow but still could not got expected result.

**Try 2**

I tried with this piece of code still could not got expected result.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: false,
    requireBase: true
});
```

**Result** :

This time getting **/#** in URL.

https://u-unalytix.milestoneinternet.com/Unalytix.Web.UAT/#/dashboard/marketing-channels

Don't know the issue. If anyone have idea about this issue then please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to make two changes.

1. Add this inside your config.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

2. Add base of your application in your index.html head tag

```
<head>
...

  <base href='/' />

...
</head>
```

Comment: Looking at your urls, it seems base url is Unalytix.Web.UAT. If above solution doesn't work, change to <base href="/Unalytix.Web.UAT" />